How to get back profiles deleted by Firefox Profile Manager...Firefox deleted all profiles instead of the one I asked
I opened firefox profile manager using firefox -p and tried to delete one profile...firefox deleted all profiles except default and default-release...even with them it renamed them with some number suffix and created new folders with the same name (default abd default-release)...I have checked /home/ubuntu18/.mozilla/firefox folder...all folders gone...UPDATE: As I was typing this there was power loss, firefox deleted old default and default-release too...horrible
Searched online for solution...I want to restore my profiles


Check your recycle bin/trash. If it's not there to restore,
the folder was deleted, so you will need to recover the files from backups or through file recovery utilities.

Depending on your OS you may recover files through file backup and file snapshot capabilities. If you do not have those enabled or available, you can use file recovery utilities to search for and recover deleted files on your disk as long as their data has not been overwritten. Given their disk store space has been marked free, they may not be identifiable or recoverable, or only in a corrupted manner. The more disk operations you do and the less free space you have, the higher the likelihood of it having been overridden.
